# Knockout validation issues

Tags: validation, knockout.js, numeric, custom-errors

I have the following issues with my knockout model validations and not sure how to resolve them. Following is my model first of all, with the validation rules:

```
var Data = function (data) {
this.Val = data;
}

function ViewModel(item) {
var parse = JSON.parse(item.d);
var self = this;
this.Name = ko.observable(parse.Name);
this.UserType = ko.observable(parse.UserType);
this.ID = ko.observable(parse.ID).extend({ required: { params: true, message: "ID is    required" }, decimal: { params: 2, message: "Should be decimal"} });
this.Username = ko.observable(parsed.Username).extend({ required: {
        onlyIf: function () {
            return self.UserType() > 1;
        }
    }   
});

this.WeeklyData = ko.observableArray([]);
var records = $.map(parse.WeeklyData, function (data) { return new Data(data) });
this.WeeklyData(records);
this.WeeklyData2 = ko.observableArray([]);
var records = $.map(parse.WeeklyData2, function (data) { return new Data(data) });
this.WeeklyData2(records);
}

ko.extenders.numeric = function (target, precision) {
var result = ko.dependentObservable({
    read: function () {
        return target().toFixed(precision);
    },
    write: target
});

result.raw = target;
return result;
};
```

Here are my problems:

1) with the ID() observable, I want to restrict it to two decimal points, so I've created the validation extender 'numeric' but it's not working. Is there anything wrong with how I'm using it and how to correct it?

2) Also, if I want to restrict an observable to whole numbers, how can I do that?

3) when I define a rule with a condition, (i.e. Username()), how do I define a custom message for that? I was able to do it for default rules, but with the conditional rules, it's not working

4) I have two observable arrays WeeklyData1 and WeeklyData2 both of which contains Data() objects. I want to have separate min/max rules for these two, for example, min/max - 1,7 for WeeklyData1 and min/max - 1,150 for WeeklyData2. How can I get it done?

4) Right now my error messages appear right next to the data field, but I want all those to appear in a single validation summary, while displaying '*' against the field. I've been told to use [Validation-bindings](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings), but I'm not sure how to use it, can someone please give an example?

It's a lot of questions, I know, but I appreciate if someone could help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of diving in your code i have created a small-small demonstrations for your questions. Ok so here we go,

> 1)  with the ID() observable, I want to restrict it to two decimal points.... and 2) Also, if I want to restrict an observable to whole numbers....

Your 1 and 2 question are pretty similar so i covered both of this in a single fiddle. [**Check this fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/iqamag/1/edit).

> 3) when I define a rule with a condition, (i.e. Username()), how do I define a custom message ....

You can use `message` property to set custom messages, [**Check this fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/owuviq/1/edit).

> 4) I have two observable arrays WeeklyData1 and WeeklyData2 both of which contains Data() objects

I am not clear which this question, what type of data both of these array contains and for what you want to set min/max rule ( array length or other ). So please clear this, than i will try to help on this.

> 5) Right now my error messages appear right next to the data field.....

This questions answer i already given in your [how to? with knockout js validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740415/how-to-with-knockout-js-validations/15741677#15741677) question (Check update).

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: re: 4) both observables contain numeric data. Say WeeklyData1 containts 21,45,54,19 (min/max should be 15/60). WeeklyData2 contains no.of days so min/max should be 0/7. Here min/max mean NOT the array length, but the boundaries for each element.

Comment: thanks heaps for your responses. They work nicely. Please answer my 4th question as well.

Comment: You can create a custom validation rule which will solve your 4th problem, check this https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: BTW, I edited your fiddle as follows, but it doesn't give any validations:                                                            function VM()
{
  var self = this;
    
  self.Age = ko.observable(0).extend({
    min: { params: 10, message: "Error"}
  });
  
  self.Salary = ko.observable(0).extend({
    numeric: 2
  });
}
basically, I want the error message to throw when I give a value like 3 for Age, but it doesn't. Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: "can you give the edited fiddle link ?" - I've got this working, sorry for the trouble.                                                       Can a custom validation rule be created on an entire observablearray? My problem is that I want to do min/max validations on each element in the array.

Comment: I think I found an example here: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/User-Contributed-Rules

Comment: I've got the following fiddler setup to demonstrate what I want, but I cant get it to work. Will you be able to help? http://jsbin.com/ocizes/9/edit